# gradle dependency not being executed

Tags: gradle

My situation is this:

- before I can package this app I need to pull a common dependency
- I pull it once to the root directory and then copy it to the subproject for speed
- I need to then build
- drop a build artifact into this copied directory

So, when I run this sample task, it pulls the dependency to the root folder but never copies it and I am just not seeing why. Below is my trimmed down kotlin build

```kotlin
import com.ullink.Msbuild
import java.io.File



plugins {
    id("com.ullink.msbuild") version "3.8" apply false

}
subprojects {
    apply(plugin = "com.ullink.msbuild")
    val solution = projectDir.walkTopDown().find { it.extension == "sln" }!!
    tasks {

        val restore by register("restore", Exec::class) {
            executable = "nuget"
            args = listOf(
                    "restore", solution.canonicalPath,
                    "-Source",
                    (getenv("NUGET_SOURCE") ?: project.properties["package.sources"]) as String
            )
        }

        val msbuild by named<Msbuild>("msbuild") {
            dependsOn(restore)
            solutionFile = solution
            projectName = project.name
            verbosity = "quiet"
            targets = listOf("Clean", "Rebuild")
            configuration = "Release"
        }

        val cpfms by register<Copy>("cpFms"){
            dependsOn(rootProject.tasks.named("pullfms"))
            doLast{
                println("cpFms do last")

                val from = projectDir
                        .listFiles()
                        .find{ it.isDirectory() && it.name.toLowerCase().startsWith("prism.core.fulfillmentmicroservice") }!!
                println("making copy ${from} -> ${projectDir}")
                from(from)

                into(projectDir)
            }
        }

        val build by named("build") {
            dependsOn(msbuild)
        }
        val cpdll by register<Copy>("cpFmsdll") {
            dependsOn(cpfms,build)

            doLast{
                println("cpFmsdll do last")
                val from = projectDir.walkTopDown().find{ it.name == "PRISMDataAdaptor.dll" }!!
                val to = projectDir.listFiles().find{ it.isDirectory() && it.name.toLowerCase().startsWith("prism.core.fulfillmentmicroservice") }!!
                println("cp dll ${from} -> ${to}")
                from(from)
                into(to)
            }
        }
        

    }
}


tasks{
    val pullFms by register("pullfms", Exec::class) {
        args = listOf(
                "install", "PRISM.Core.FulfillmentMicroService",
                "-Source", (getenv("NUGET_PUBLISH") ?: project.properties["publish.repo"]) as String
        )
        executable = "nuget"
    }
}
```

so when I run
`gradle :adaptor-cwi_ky_statewide_smd:cpFmsdll`

I expect that it will

1. pull my dependency as defined in the root project
2. copy it to the local project
3. build
4. copy the build dll into the folder in step 2

The dry run shows what I would expect:

```
PS C:\Users\cbongiorno\dev\sterling\prism\prism-adaptors> gradle --dry-run :adaptor-cwi_ky_statewide_smd:cpFmsdll
:adaptor-cwi_ky_statewide_smd:assemble SKIPPED
:adaptor-cwi_ky_statewide_smd:check SKIPPED
:adaptor-cwi_ky_statewide_smd:restore SKIPPED
:adaptor-cwi_ky_statewide_smd:msbuild SKIPPED
:adaptor-cwi_ky_statewide_smd:build SKIPPED
:pullfms SKIPPED
:adaptor-cwi_ky_statewide_smd:cpFms SKIPPED
:adaptor-cwi_ky_statewide_smd:cpFmsdll SKIPPED
```

but the execution doesn't actually do it?! The directly isn't copied in the the local project but it is in the root project

```
PS C:\Users\cbongiorno\dev\sterling\prism\prism-adaptors> gradle :adaptor-cwi_ky_statewide_smd:cpFmsdll

> Task :adaptor-cwi_ky_statewide_smd:restore
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '15.5.180.51428' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\bin'.
All packages listed in packages.config are already installed.

> Task :pullfms
Feeds used:
  https://repo.dev.backgroundcheck.com/nexus/repository/nuget-group/

Installing package 'PRISM.Core.FulfillmentMicroService' to 'C:\Users\cbongiorno\dev\sterling\prism\prism-adaptors'.
  CACHE https://repo.dev.backgroundcheck.com/nexus/repository/nuget-group/FindPackagesById()?id='PRISM.Core.FulfillmentMicroService'&semVerLevel=2.0.0
Package "PRISM.Core.FulfillmentMicroService.0.0.77" is already installed.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1m 6s
3 actionable tasks: 3 executed
PS C:\Users\cbongiorno\dev\sterling\prism\prism-adaptors> ls | select -Last 20


    Directory: C:\Users\cbongiorno\dev\sterling\prism\prism-adaptors


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----        7/14/2020  10:08 PM                gradle
d-----        7/21/2020   3:36 PM                infra
d-----        5/13/2020   4:17 AM                PRISM-Adaptor-QC_LA_SaintBernard
d-----        8/25/2020   4:25 PM                PRISM.Core.FulfillmentMicroService.0.0.77
d-----        7/14/2020   8:07 AM                routeadaptor-apinationwide_msmj1_dre
d-----        5/13/2020   4:18 AM                serviceadaptor-cwi_ky_statewide_smd
d-----        5/13/2020   4:18 AM                serviceadaptor-cwi_ny_statewide
d-----        5/13/2020   4:18 AM                serviceadaptor-qc_ny_statewide
-a----        7/14/2020   8:07 AM           2581 .gitattributes
-a----        8/25/2020   4:22 PM          13996 .gitignore
-a----        8/25/2020   4:51 PM           6653 build.gradle.kts
-a----        7/21/2020   3:36 PM            987 Dockerfile
-a----        8/14/2020   4:28 PM            206 gradle.properties
-a----        7/14/2020  10:08 PM           5764 gradlew
-a----        7/14/2020  10:08 PM           2942 gradlew.bat
-a----        7/21/2020   3:36 PM           2222 Jenkinsfile
-a----        5/13/2020   4:17 AM          11565 PRISM-Adaptors.txt
-a----        7/14/2020   8:07 AM            722 README.md
-a----        8/25/2020   3:24 PM            416 settings.gradle.kts
-a----        7/14/2020   8:07 AM            978 sh.exe.stackdump


PS C:\Users\cbongiorno\dev\sterling\prism\prism-adaptors> ls .\adaptor-cwi_ky_statewide_smd\


    Directory: C:\Users\cbongiorno\dev\sterling\prism\prism-adaptors\adaptor-cwi_ky_statewide_smd


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----        7/21/2020   1:24 PM                build
d-----        7/21/2020   1:14 PM                CWI_KY_STATEWIDE_SMDSol
-a----        5/13/2020   4:17 AM           2581 .gitattributes


PS C:\Users\cbongiorno\dev\sterling\prism\prism-adaptors>
```

at the end I see to basically need to replicate this code (example):

```
nuget.exe restore CWI_TN_DAVIDSON_SMDSol\CWI_TN_DAVIDSON_SMDSol.sln -source "https://www.nuget.org/api/v2;http://prism-prod-oct/NuGetLocalServer/nuget"
MSBuild.exe C:\PRISMGit\adaptor-cwi_tn_davidson_smd\CWI_TN_DAVIDSON_SMDSol\CWI_TN_DAVIDSON_SMDSol.sln /t:Clean /p:Configuration=Release
MSBuild.exe C:\PRISMGit\adaptor-cwi_tn_davidson_smd\CWI_TN_DAVIDSON_SMDSol\CWI_TN_DAVIDSON_SMDSol.sln /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release

Set-Location C:\PRISMGit\adaptor-cwi_tn_davidson_smd\CWI_TN_DAVIDSON_SMDSol\PRISM.Adaptor.CWI.TN.DAVIDSON.SMD\

$Package = Find-Package -Name PRISM.Core.FulfillmentMicroService -Source http://prism-prod-oct/NuGetLocalServer/nuget

NuGet.exe install $Package.Name  -Version $Package.Version -source http://prism-prod-oct/NuGetLocalServer/nuget

Copy-Item -Path .\bin\Release\PRISMDataAdaptor.dll -Destination (".\"+$Package.Name+ "." + $Package.Version+"\")   -Recurse -Force
```

Comment: `projectDir` as in `val from = projectDir` in the subproject's copy task refers to the subproject's directory, but the artifact is in the root project directory. Is this the issue?

Comment: It doesn't seem to even be attempting the copy.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the configuration of your copy task:

```
val cpfms by register<Copy>("cpFms") {
    dependsOn(rootProject.tasks.named("pullfms"))
    doLast {
        // ...
        from(from)
        into(projectDir)
    }
}

val cpdll by register<Copy>("cpFmsdll") {
    dependsOn(cpfms,build)
    doLast {
        // …
        from(from)
        into(to)
    }
}
```

The issue is that you configuration your copy task during the its execution. So I think your tasks is not configured and then not executed.

You can see an example of configuration in the [Gradle Copy documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html). There is no `doLast` part.

Your copy task are relying on file/directory that are created by an earlier task.
I think you should considered that the file will be here and use include from regarding a pattern and not regarding that files are really here (which may explain why you used `doLast`)

Example:

```
val cpfms by register<Copy>("cpFms") {
    dependsOn(rootProject.tasks.named("pullfms"))
    from("**/PRISMDataAdaptor.dll")
    into("prism.core.fulfillmentmicroservice")
}
```

Comment: I've tried it with the configuration as you have it - the problem is, I think, it's attempting to resolve the file it needs to copy at configuration time, which doesn't exist (yet) and thus NPEs, so, I tried to move it to the doLast. But, I think because, are you point out, there is no doLast, it basically sees an unconfigured copy task. In explaining it just now, I see what the problem is - I might know how to fix it. Your solution may work, but it isn't addressing the issue directly. Let me see what I can do

Comment: I gave you an upvote for putting me on the right path and potentially giving me a better solution than what I have (haven't tried it yet). However, for the bounty it had to solve the problem as proposed. It's challenging to get any answer for gradle on SOF, so I am sure I will be back offering another

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks to @dwursteisen for putting me on the right track. Solving this specific problem required use of delegation:

```kotlin
      val cpfms by register<Copy>("cpFms") {
            dependsOn(rootProject.tasks.named("pullfms"))

            val from by lazy {
                rootProject.projectDir.listFiles()
                        .find { it.isDirectory() && it.name.toLowerCase().startsWith("prism.core.fulfillmentmicroservice") }
            }
            from(from)
            into(projectDir)
        }
```

This now, actually works. However, the above sample may actually be better as it's just simply less complicated.